cypress-cucumber-preprocessor dry option not working
How to use dry run option in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor package, so that I can get respective step definition for feature files. I have gone through the following link and used the command
npx cypress-cucumber-diagnostics

but it is not working. Do I need to install any different package to get this option. Getting this error
Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cypress-cucumber-diagnostics


It's been changed to dry run option. Refer to Change log v21.0.0 - Sep 29 2024

You need to have @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor installed.
